# InvalidOperationException with $top or $skip in OData Expand

Tags: entity-framework-core, odata, automapper

We are using EF Core 3.1 with OData 7.5.1. We are also using DTOs and Automapper 10.1.1 to map our entities to these DTOs.

I am trying to expand only the first couple of items in a nested collection using the following query:

https://localhost:44347/v1/odata/Subcategories?$top=3$expand=Products($top=2)

If I run this query on the entities instead of the DTOs, all the query options added within Expand work just fine.

However, if we run this on the DTOs after ProjectTo, I receive the following exception:

[Shortened for brevity]

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression '(ProjectionBindingExpression: 0)' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ConditionalExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
```

So, this works

```
        [AllowAnonymous, HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductSubcategoryDto> options)
        {
            IQueryable<ProductSubcategory> subs = DbContext.ProductSubcategories;
   
            IQueryable queryable = options.ApplyTo(subs); 
   
            return Ok(queryable);    
        }
```

but this one throws

```
        [AllowAnonymous, HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductSubcategoryDto> options)
        {   
            IQueryable<ProductSubcategoryDto> subsDto = DbContext.ProductSubcategories.ProjectTo<ProductSubcategoryDto>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

            IQueryable queryable = options.ApplyTo(subsDto);    

            return Ok(queryable);
        }
```

And I have also tried the Queryable Extensions and the query options inside the expand are completely ignored, except $select.

```
        [AllowAnonymous, HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductSubcategoryDto> options)
        {
             return Ok(await DbContext.ProductSubcategories.GetQueryAsync(Mapper, options));
        }
```

All our DTOs and ProjectTo calls work fine outside this context.

Am I doing everything I right? Is this a bug with EF Core or Automapper?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData

Comment: Do you have a mapper for the Products that you expand?

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu. I've already tried and Queryable Extensions seem to ignore $skip and $top within Expand as well. I've just opened [an issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData/issues/68) there as well.

Comment: @Stutje yes, I do. The mapping works just fine everywhere else. It is as straightforward as it gets for the mapping from Product to ProductDto.

Comment: I have figured the reason for why the Queryable Extensions is ignoring these queries. It is because we call EnableLowerCamelCase on the EDM during building and the binding member name is not compared with the updated names but rather the original Pascal case for the expansions. Details outlined in the [issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData/issues/68).